# Python: is it possible to do PCA with a vector with multiple dimensions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I would like to try to do `PCA` using the description [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)
PCA(n_components=2)
```

Is it possible to do the same with an array with different dimensions such as the following?

```
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2, 3], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2, 3]])
```

if I try I get the following error:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You are abusing NumPy a bit with the definition of X. You will end up with a dtype of `object` rather than an array of integers. If you print the value of `X` you sill see it's an array of list objects.  It's not clear to me (and probably also sklearn) what you intend the value of the third dimension to be in the 2-element sublists. You should clean your data so all the dimensions are the same.

Comment: I believe PCA and similar methods all assume vectors of equal length. Related, why would you want to do this? I do not know of any sound analysis methods where this would be desirable.

Comment: @MattL. I would like to do dimensionality reduction on data that have different dimensions like the example above

Comment: Right, but dimensionality reduction is performed on vectors of the same the length. The idea is to compare apples to apples, not apples to squirrels or coconuts. Why do some of your vectors have fewer dimensions than others?

Comment: Just to be clear...nothing in Numpy is going to work well with an array like that. It's not just PCA. Even `X + 1` will raise an exception.

Comment: @MattL. for instance if I have the information about the different variables. For instance, for a person I can have information about the 1) age and 2) the different locations he visited, 3) the list of the money the spent in a week, etc. I would like to reduce the dimensionality of each person.

Comment: Right, so say you have people where you know the age and some where you don't. Your choices include (1) leave out the age column entirely, (2) fill in a placeholder value like zero for the unknown ages or (3) fill in the median or mean age if age is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible given the mathematical background of Principal Component Analysis. PCA is a rotation in the high-dimensional space.